# Is there a way to set different headers on different pages in a pdf generated flying saucer and iText?

Tags: itext, flying-saucer

My requirement is like this, I would like to have headers from page 2 of the pdf but not in page 1. Is it possible to do that using css counter and @page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check my answer at [iText Flying Saucer pdf headers and ignoring html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625379/itext-flying-saucer-pdf-headers-and-ignoring-html/6625714#comment-7877864), you can customize the header/footer content based on the page number, i know this is not a answer using flying-saucer. but it works for me.